# Error 500 en mi sitio web en producción (PHP)

Tags: php

Acabo de subir mi sitio web a producción pero este me esta lanzando un error 500. Hace mas o menos unas 8 horas compre un hosting en **Intelplanet** y subí mi sitio a Internet pero este no se visualiza y imprime un error 500 por pantalla.

Me puse en contacto con el soporte y este dice que es un error en mi *.htaccess* pero en localhost me funciona bien y incluso elimine el archivo *.htaccess* y me lanza el mismo error, aun que volví a subir el archivo claro esta.

### Código .htaccess:

```
# Eliminar el .php en todos los archivos
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# URL Amigable POST
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2

# URL Amigable EDIT POST
RewriteRule ^edit-post/([0-9]+) edit-post.php?id=$1&title=$2

# Error 404
ErrorDocument 404 https://thecanario.com/404

Dominio de mi sitio web: https://thecanario.com/
```

No conozco la pagina en el **cpanel** donde muestra los errores, pero creo que será esta.

[image: Pagina de errores cpanel]

### Posible error según mi opinión

Yo creo que el error esta en la conexión a la base de datos ya que tengo una pagina llamada **contact.php** y cuando elimino la conexión a la base de datos esta se visualiza correctamente sin ningún problema, pero desde que vuelvo a des comentar la linea de código que requiere la conexiona a la **DB** esta vuelve a lanzar el error 500.

### Conexión a la base de datos

```
<?php
// Conexion a la base de datos
try{
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thecanar_io', 'usuario', 'contraseña');
}catch(PDOExeption $e){
  echo "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error nuestros ingenieros trabajan para solucionarlo: " . $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

Quiero aclarar que este mismo código utilizo en un sitio web en producción que tengo claro esta con las credenciales diferentes y este me funciona sin problema.

### conclusión

Yo opino que el error no esta en el archivo **.htaccess** mas bien el error de conexión a la base de datos, ya que la pagina funciona sin problema cuando quito la conexión a la base de datos y si el problema fuera el htaccess la pagina daría error aunque quite la conexión a la **DB** y además tengo el mismo código .htaccess funcionando en otro sitio web en producción sin problemas.

Comment: Te refieres a los mensajes de console en el navegador ? porque allí no me lanza ningún error

Comment: Revisa el log de errores en el servidor, los errores 500 son errores de servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se como revisar los log 500 en el servidor.

Comment: Tienes que comprobar qué versiones de **PHP** estás usando en tu entorno local y en el del *hosting*, tienen que ser la misma porque hay funciones que quedan obsoletas entre versiones. Recordar que el directorio por defecto en `Cpanel` es `html_public`. Si pudieras enviar una captura de tu directorio en el `Cpanel` de tu *hosting* se podría hacer un poco más.

Comment: El [error 500](https://codigoshttp.com/500/) es un error de servidor, por lo que es imposible saber qué es lo que lo causa sin tener acceso a la configuración y/o al código. Si nos enseñas el contenido del `.htaccess`, puede que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Nos sería de utilidad que compartieras el contenido del archivo `.htaccess` y la versión de Apache que ejecuta tu alojamiento. También sería bueno que nos dijeras qué aparece en el registro de error del servidor web. En el panel de control de tu proveedor (Intelplanet) deberías tener alguna forma de acceder a estos archivos de registro.

Comment: @OdeiAlba ya he editado la pregunta

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 7.4 de PHP tanto en local como en producción. No creo que sea un error de servidor, esto es otra cosa

Comment: A mí me parece que sí tienes errores en `.htaccess`, pero si crees que el problema es referente a base de datos, entonces edita la pregunta y agrega el código que usas para conectar.

Comment: Ok. Eso hare. Pero no se te hace extraño que si elimino la conexión a la base de datos la pagina se visualice sin problema y desde que quito el comentario de la conexión este nuevamente deje de visualizarse y ha aparezca ese estorboso error 500 nuevamente.

Comment: El error en ese trozo de código es tipográfico, te falta una `c` en `PDOExeption`, debería ser `PDOException` y por eso no se captura la excepción en el bloque `try ... catch`, generando error 500.

Comment: @Triby Gracias por notar el error. No me había dado de cuenta pero efectivamente tenia un error en mi conexión a la base de datos. Ya lo he he solucionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre solucionar mi error gracias a un tutorial de **Youtube**. Resulta que yo estaba creando mal el usuario a mi base de datos. La opción correcta era crear un asistente de base de datos y yo pulsaba la opción **bases de datos MYSQL**

[Este es el tutorial que me ayudo a solucionar mi problema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBDw67Tcdn8&t=142s&ab_channel=GersonMoralesLife)

Efectivamente como yo sospechaba mi problema no venia del archivo *.htaccess* como me decían los soportes. Ya mi pregunta fue solucionada